# IE 11 duplicate X-UA-Compatible tag in DotNetNuke

Tags: internet-explorer, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, x-ua-compatible

On one of our sites, when going to any form that has recaptch in IE 11 (or 10) - recaptcha doesn't work.  What we've found out is that in all version of IE excluding Edge - there's a duplicate X-UA-Compatible meta tag being added.

We already have `<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />` on the page, but in IE 10 and lower it's adding the following immediately AFTER the `head` tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
<![CDATA[<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" >]]>
```

This is obviously before our own tag in the markup thus seemingly overrides our setting which is still present.

We've tried many tasks

- disabling Google Tag Manager
- removing google analytics
- disabling 3rd party modules

We even cloned our site on the exact same server.  The temp domain worked flawlessly.  But once we pointed the dns to the temp site - the issue persisted.

We assumed it may be related to [Microsoft's Compatibility View](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/gg622935(v=vs.60)).  By adding it to be bypassed by IE (browser level setting) everything works as expected - but this isn't a solution for our clients website.

But oddly now even in chrome if you change the user-agent string Chrome too receives the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">` - so that scraps the idea of Microsofts CV lists.

The site was running DNN 7.4.2, and we upgraded to 8.0.4 - and the issue persists.  I have scanned both source code bases for DNN and nothing seems to point the way of being the issue.

This issue is thus disabling all of our clients contact-us forms - but only for users in IE.  My team and I are at a complete loss.  I'm hoping someone here may have a nugget of info to help fix the issue.

Comment: It must already be in the Master Page markup. You should remove it from your master pages.. and only use it in webforms where you require it.. Ideally you should stop using x-ua meta tags, and convert your existing markup to html5 standards. To find out which IE emulation mode has been applied to a web page... f12>Emulation tab.... eg. IE8, x-ua meta tag, IE11, default, IE7 , user compatibility list.

Comment: DotNetNuke doesn't use Master pages.  I've checked our skin, and the source and cannot find where it's being injected from.

Answer (score 0):

We seem to have found the answer and it was w/i a third party module.  I know we disabled the module (permission only for admins) and that didn't work last week, but must've been part of the caching that IE does.  I retried turning off the permissions for the module and got reCaptcha working.

We are using EasyDNNGallery - and I see they have a call off to `https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js` - I cannot say verbatim that `plusone.js` is the culprit - I was just looking for any other google references that could be interfering.

This makes sense since if we cloned the site - the EasyDNNGallery wasn't activated since it's a domain level activation.

In the end we kept running in circles due to a false positive.  Always retry tests!